# Why URL and linked pages submissions for Google?

Tags: google-search-console, web-crawlers, google-index

Why Google Webmaster Tools have limitation on URL and linked pages submissions?

Is there any solution to submit more than 10 URL?

Answer (score 1):

There's rarely a need to submit more than 10 URLs at once to Google's index. If your website is indexed, allows search engine crawlers to crawl it, and all pages are reachable by following links, then search engines will revisit your website and index your new pages eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Because it could then be abused to index a single page 100 times per minute, which would waste Google's server power and bandwidth.

You may look at Google as a machine with limitless resources but it is not so, every byte and cpu cycle counts :)

As for the 500 and 10 links submission limit per week - it is set reasonably high, most smaller sites do not really generate 500 new unique pages per week.

If you mange more than one site and hit the limit you could theoretically create a second webmaster tools account to get a new set, but you would then have all of your assets stretched too wide.